# Idiomatic Function Transformation of A => (B, C) to A => (C, B)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, combinators

Is there an idiomatic way of transforming a function

```
val x: A => (B, C) = ...
```

to

```
val y: A => (C, B) = ...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- You can change a `(B, C)` to a `(C, B)` using [`Tuple2.swap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2).
- Turning a `A => (B, C)` into a `A => (C, B)` can then be done using `.andThen(_.swap)`.

For example :

```
scala> val a = (i: Int) => (s"$i", i.toDouble)
a: Int => (String, Double) = <function1>

scala> val b = a.andThen(_.swap)
b: Int => (Double, String) = <function1>

scala> b(5)
res1: (Double, String) = (5.0,5)
```